# How to drag and drop bitmap like InstaWeather Android app did

Tags: android, bitmap, touch

I would like to drag and drop bitmap like InstaWeather Android app did.

Comment: This isn't way to ask question here, you must try something before posting.

Comment: sorry, i'm really a newbie in android. i've just read Android API from Google, but it doesn't have any specify example on each one. I'm trying to do something like InstaWeather and blend mode color like Instagram, but i dont know what is the mecharnism for this. Sorry, i will not asking something kind like this again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You check out below links to implement the onLongTouch Drag event.Also Check the Developer guide for the Drag & Drop touch event [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html)

1) [Link 1](http://blahti.wordpress.com/2011/01/17/moving-views-part-2/)
2) [Link 2](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0wYSnCBkoR6a1VFdy1VdmZSU2E1eDhuUXVQYnpEQQ/edit?pli=1)
3) [Link 3](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/12/android-drag-and-drop-tutorial.html)
4) [Link 4](https://capdroid.wordpress.com/)

I hope it will help you.

Thanks.

Comment: Wow, it's great for me. So good. Thank you so much @Grishu. I love StackOverFlow! Thanks alot @Grishu!

Comment: You're Welcome @Vinh Le. If it helped you then please kindly vote up dear :)